# Ссылка в формате предзагрузки

Tags: php, css, href

Объясните пожалуйста каким образом можно сделать следующее:
При открытии новой вкладки в хроме он открывает поиск и несколько "часто посещаемых сайтов".
Я хочу себе организовать что-то вроде закладок такого формата.
сделать картинку ссылкой - несложно.
Но, как сделать попроще ссылку - "снимком" того что увидит юзер после перехода.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Маленький `iframe` + масштаб :D

Comment: Спасибо. только сейчас добрался до способ.
По сути все решилось так -  #frame { transform: scale(0.3)}

Answer (score 0):

Подобная проблема решается так.
К элементу  применяется стиль "transform: scale(0.1)".

И выглядит все замечательно.